# Travel from Munich to Scotland avoiding flight

Tags: trains, germany, ferries, scotland, ships

I want to travel from south Germany (say Munich) to Scotland (say Edinburgh), but with no flight as I want to protect the climate.
Meanwhile it is again possible to book the Eurostar train connection to London via Deutsche Bahn.
But then I have to book another train to Edinburgh.

Is there a ship connection? How can I get there best in regards to price and travel time?

Comment: "protect the climate" you do realize that trains and boats also require power and that power requires some sort of generation method, right? Electricity doesn't just appear out of nowhere (well, until someone figures out how to capture lightning...)

Comment: @FreeMan:  No mode of transport is completely environmentally harmless, but some modes of transport are much less environmentally harmful than others.  [See this link.](https://ourworldindata.org/travel-carbon-footprint)

Comment: @FreeMan train travel gives off a tiny fraction of the emissions of plane travel.

Comment: People, while I do not agree with the first comment in this series, claiming train travel is also damaging to the climate, it is a legitimate comment and should not be deleted. So please stop flagging it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148140/discussion-on-question-by-nick-travel-from-munich-to-scotland-avoiding-flight); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 29):

Maybe not the cheapest but possibly the quickest, easiest, and most comfortable is by train.  Munich to Paris.  Paris to London via Eurostar through the tunnel.  London to Edinburgh.

You can substitute Brussels or Amsterdam for Paris (thanks to Nicolas Formichella).

Substituting coaches for some or all of the trains might reduce the cost but it will be slower and less comfortable.

You could rent or buy a car and drive but this is liable to be the most expensive and maybe even the slowest.

Addition

Smarste reminds me that the motivation of avoiding flying is to reduce emissions.  In which case, the train is probably your best choice. A big advantage of trains is that they are (mostly) powered by electricity which can be produced by means other than burning stuff.  The car is probably the worst unless you have an unusually efficient car with many passengers.

Michael Seifert added a useful link in a comment: https://ourworldindata.org/travel-carbon-footprint

Comment: My idea would be to rent a car onsite to drive through the Highlands, but not to go there by car.

Comment: Munich to Paris or Munich to Amsterdam/Brussels

Comment: My wife and did a somewhat similar trip from Copenhagen to Birmingham by train last year.  However, we got out for a break at multiple points e,g. Paris.  However, our objective was not just to get there but to have a relaxing and enjoyable trip.  It worked.

Comment: If you can book early the price for train tickets can be very good. Train tickets on short notice are expensive.

Comment: @Willeke Especially so in the UK.  Never just walk into a station and ask for a ticket.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Brussels, yes, but Amsterdam is a pretty significant detour.

Comment: "You could rent or buy a car and drive but this is liable to be the most expensive and maybe even the slowest." then your CO2 emissions can actually be higher than flying the same journey https://www.statista.com/statistics/1185559/carbon-footprint-of-travel-per-kilometer-by-mode-of-transport/

Comment: @smartse Good point.  I forgot for a moment that the motivation was reducing carbon emissions rather than a fear or dislike of flying.

Comment: @badjohn this is generally good advice, but a handful of train lines in the UK don't offer advance fares. I moved away from Cambridge a couple of years ago, but for the decade I was there the line that ran the trains to King's Cross (which were much faster and more comfortable, but a little more expensive than the trains to Liverpool Street), Great Northern, didn't offer advanced fares (at least not on the Cambridge-London route)

Comment: @Tristan Yes, UK train fares are a very complex subject and how to get an optimal fare could be the subject of a doctorate degree.  However, the OP just seemed to want to know how it could be done.  If they want advice on getting the best price then they should post a follow up question.

Comment: The connection in London is a very easy one, easier than many London train connections, because St Pancras station for the Eurostar service and Kings Cross station for Edinburgh are next door to each other.

Comment: "Car may be the slowest" I remember sitting on Eurostar, the train drove past a motorway, and my GPS told me I was _exceeding_ the speed limit by 110 miles per hour.

Comment: @gnasher729 The top (legal) speed of the car won't match the train.  Where a car could win is that you won't have to wait for connections (except when you cross the channel).  However, this is a long trip so you would either need to drive for an unreasonably long time or have a team.  Either way, not recommended.

Comment: some of the comments about cars are very off-base.  Car is ***overwhelmingly*** cheaper for a family.  secondly, because public transport ***doesn't actually get you anywhere*** other than a train station or airport, the (often spectacular) cost of taxis at each end (not to mention, constantly throughout your stay or trip anyway) usually wildly exceeds the cost of the train or cheap air ticket.  ..

Comment: Thirdly ( @gnasher729 !) we lived in (for example) a rural area near Aberdeen. (By coincidence we'd often go to exactly Bavaria, or nearby regions like dolomites, Austria etc - just as in this question).  You pile everyone in the car and have a pleasant drive through Ye Olde Britain. By the time you're changing diapers in the channel tunnel, you'd still be waiting on a .. bus? some sort of rural train? or you'd be dealing with the insanity of changing train stations with five suitcases in london (what, on the tube?) not to mention the uglier situation in Paris. the differences are stark!

Comment: @Fattie Remember that the OP is not trying to find the cheapest or even most comfortable method but to reduce emissions.  Switching from a plane to a car might or might not achieve that.  Switching to a train has a good chance of doing so.  The OP spoke of "I" so it might be a single person journey.

Answer (score 17):

As usual [The man in seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/Germany.htm) has lots of advice on the subject.

See the section [London to Stuttgart & Munich](https://www.seat61.com/Germany.htm#london-to-stuttgart-and-munich-by-train) which gives 4 options to London:

- TGV to Paris, Eurostar to London
- ICE to Cologne, Thalys or ICE to Brussels, Eurostar to London
- Nightjet sleeper train to Brussels, Eurostar to London
- Trains to Hoek van Holland, ferry to Harwich, train to London
- Trains to Amsterdam, ferry to Newcastle, train
- Trains to Rotterdam, ferry to Hull, train

These mostly point to London, so another train to Edinburgh is needed. Itineraries from the various harbours used by ferries to Edinburg may or may not make sense.

The page has **lots** of details about each of these options, including timetables, prices, pictures and tips.

There are also sections for:

- [London to Germany via the Harwich-Hoek ferry](https://www.seat61.com/Germany.htm#london-to-germany-via-the-harwich-hoek-ferry)
- [UK to Germany by ferry from Hull or Newcastle](https://www.seat61.com/Germany.htm#uk-to-germany-by-ferry-from-newcastle-or-hull)
- [Starting from other UK towns & cities](https://www.seat61.com/european-travel-from-uk-regions.htm)

Comment: I think there are direct coaches from the ferry near Newcastle to Edinburgh, otherwise it will be a coach to the station and trains from there, as well as the coach from Amsterdam to the ferry. I guess Rotterdam - Hull has the same options and difficulties. I would go for train all the way unless you love ferries.

Comment: The Rotterdam and Amsterdam (actually IJmuiden) ferry terminals are each about 30 km from the respective main train stations. In both cases the journey requires over an hour by public transportation.  I didn't look to see whether the situation is similar on the other side in England.

Comment: +1 for referring to the man in seat 61. Why not include https://www.seat61.com/sleeper-to-scotland.htm as well?

Comment: there's a (Vienna-)Munich-Paris nightjet as well (but for Bruxelles you need to get to Nurnberg first)

Comment: There used to be a ferry from Zeebrugge to Rosyth in Scotland but unfortunately it hasn't run for a few years, despite occasional claims it will be restored. In any case North Sea ferries are not always particularly pleasant, certainly the Netherlands-Newcastle one, especially at weekends when they're often full of drunk people. Newcastle to much of Scotland is easy by train; Hull to Scotland not so much.

Answer (score 16):

The comfortable route, if you can sleep on a train:

- NightJet 468 from Munich East to Paris.
- EuroStar from Paris to London
- Caledonian Sleeper from London to Glasgow/Edinburgh/Inverness/Aberdeen/Fort William

This gives you some time in Paris and/or London as well, depending on which EuroStar you take.

Comment: Although the Caledonian Sleeper is much more expensive than other long-distance London-Scotland trains. (And it's had occasional issues and threats of cancellation, so do check it's still running.)

Answer (score 9):

The part of the world you want to travel through has some of the best public transport systems in the world. There are countless options for travelling with trains (faster, more comfortable, more expensive) or buses (slower, less comfortable, cheaper). Not possible to list them all, but you should definitely have a look at the Seat61 website (see jcaron's answer). However, it's not likely you'll be able to buy a single ticket for your entire journey.

The fastest and most straightforward (but probably not the cheapest) option would be a Eurostar train to London and another train to Scotland from there. If you're not on a tight schedule and are willing to experiment a bit, you can search timetables for cheaper connections, either trains or buses. You can also cross the English Channel as a foot passenger on a ferry. There are countless ferry connections, from France or from the Netherlands, and you can save a lot of money by doing some research.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that you can buy a rail pass (e.g. InterRail) for the UK (or for any other country but a UK pass would be most useful), if you want to travel around. Just keep in mind that some long-distance train services in the UK (as well as in other countries) require a reservation that must be bought separately if you have a rail pass.

And the last piece of advice: don't forget your passport! EU nationals in general cannot enter the UK with their ID cards.

Answer (score 4):

The train connection mentioned by badjohn is probably the most straight-forward non-flying way to get from Munich to Edinburgh. Leaving Munich at 8:45 in the morning, you can (provided everything goes according to plan) reach Edinburgh at 21:24 on the same day. Unfortunately, to my knowledge there is no operator that sells a single ticket for the entire connection, which will increase both price and the risk of delays.

The most sensible way to incorporate a ferry could be to to take the train to Amsterdam instead (still takes about 9h), then the overnight ferry to Newcastle. From Newcastle to Edinburgh its just another 1:30 on the train. You can get a single train ticket from Munich to Amsterdam, but the ferry doesn't seem to be cheap. If you are travelling with multiple people, this option probably becomes more attractive as you can share a cabin. Otherwise, the main advantage of this option probably is that you are not spending over 10h on a train in a single day.

Comment: Buying a London International (CIV) ticket works exactly as a single ticket due to the CIV (Convention Internationale des Voyages, if your Eurostar is delayed and you miss your UK Train)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I have tried to buy CIV tickets last year, failed, and others confirmed they could not buy them either.

Comment: The IJmuiden ferry terminal is not particularly close to Amsterdam; Google suggests the train to Haarlem and buses or taxi from there.  The travel time from Munich is between 9 and 10 hours.  All of the itineraries that arrive in time for the closing of check-in at 16:45 are inconvenient in one way or another; the only one that really makes sense is the 7:30 ICE to Frankfurt, then to Amsterdam and Haarlem, arriving at 16:19, followed by a 14 km taxi ride to the ferry.  Similar problems exist in Newcastle; the simplest way to get to the train station is going to be by taxi,  also 14 km.

Comment: @phoog, the IJmuiden Newcastle ferry runs a connecting coach service on both ends, from Amsterdam not Haarlem. And Scotland bound coaches on the UK end.

Answer (score 4):

I have done something similar a few years back (in 2019), for health reasons.

I used an Interrail Global Pass (https://www.interrail.eu/en), which is 258€ (less for age <27 or >60) for both trips (+80€ seat reservations, I'll talk about that later). Not necessarily cheap, but convenient. And you have two days left that you can use in Scotland - like going to Glasgow, Dundee or Inverness.

Our Itinerary was via Frankfurt and Brussels - which (at least back then) was quicker and more convenient than Paris.

All usual German trains are included in the Interrail pass, night trains (and the Eurostar and many British trains) do require seat reservations. As these reservations can be sold out quickly, we booked them once they became available (120 days or 90 days before departure). Deutsche Bahn agents helped me to buy these reservations, but I find it just as easy to buy directly on the interrail website.

For the British seat reservations, I had to call the British train company (and it being Britian, there are different ones...). I used LNER, they have direct service from London's Kings Cross to Scotland, and back then they didn't even want payment for the seat reservation - I just got a code I could enter at a ticket machine in Kings Cross and it printed my seat reservation. I didn't get to sit on that seat - to me it looked like it was not common in these trains to have a reservation at all - but I got a different seat just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I hate flying, all the security, delays, etc.  Would rather work on the train.  Eat in the dining car, the food may be lousy, cost high, but you can't beat the view.

I've taken parts of this trip (Basel - London) and if it were me, I would choose the following routing:

- Munich to Frankfurt, probably hourly ICE trains
- Frankfurt to Brussels, I used the "ICE International"  IIRC 4 a day
- Overnight in Brussels, I usually stayed in the Ibis right across from the Brussels Midi station
- First Eurostar to London
- Walk across the street from St Pancras (not Pancreas) to Kings Cross and grab one of the services to Edinburgh

I realise I could travel via Paris, but it's an unpleasant station change (Gare de Lyon to Gare du Nord) with suitcases on the Metro.

And by all means, use a Eurail or Interrail pass.  Especially in the UK, where the ordinary fares are very high.

Another reason to break your journey in Brussels is that in the recent past there have been some service disruptions with the ICE International where one is cancelled, or departs from Brussels Nord, or worse yet, you need to board a Belgian train to connect with the rerouted ICE waiting in some small station in some small town (forget where, somewhere near Liege) along with hundreds of other irate travelers.

I always felt that the Eurostar should be the first train of the day, as it's a hard deadline and there is no last-minute service as there is with Renfe in Barcelona, Madrid, etc.  Eurostar check-in these days is every bit as nasty as in an airport, particularly post Brexit.

For what it's worth, the ICE International trains need to operate on both the German 25kv electrification and the legacy 3kv DC in Belgium, very probably there aren't that many spare trains, so if one breaks down, something gets cancelled.

Frankly, I've had too many cancellations and have given up, but will try again maybe later in the Fall.

The Brussels Ibis used to be fairly inexpensive (EUR 70) but times have changed and it's probably more.

Alternatively, there is Amsterdam, and there is an Ibis right at the station, but it's a longer journey (no cost difference using Interrail) and it's unclear whether the Ibis would be inexpensive.

Last and certainly least, I normally don't reserve seats in Germany, mostly to be able to change plans on the fly when something is late.  This has never been a problem for me, but I travel light.

My preference is to avoid night trains.  When I was a young man, I would travel to Vienna on a night train, but sleep in a compartment with the seats folded.  First class helped here.

Comment: For a cheaper bed in Brussels, if you don't mind sharing the room hostel-style, check out the Meininger hotel next to the main station.
Paris metro can be a challenge given that there are many stairs in the hallways. But Gare de l'Est (where the ICE from Frankfurt arrives) and Gare du Nord (where the Eurostar departs) are just a couple blocks away from each other. Don't bother riding the metro for just one stop, it's much easier to roll the suitcases in the street for this transfer.

Comment: I've walked from Gare de l'Est to Gare du Nord (with a large-ish suitcase) some years ago, before trains originating in Switzerland terminated in Gare de Lyon.

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, the connection is there and pretty convenient.

Regarding the financial aspect, do consider an Interrail (if you are a EU resident) or Eurail (if from outside EU) pass. You pay a flat fee for a fixed number of travel days. Can be bought at any train station, or online as an electronic pass with the mobile app delivered in 30 minutes. Note that the Interrail pass cannot be used in your country of residence if you are from the EU, with the exception of two days for getting out and coming back.

You break even pretty quickly when compared to same-day flexible fares in Germany and UK. For example, you can get four days of travel for less than the price of same-day one-way point-to-point tickets bought at the normal price.

Do not hesitate to splurge on the 1st class, the pass prices are just 25% more. It is less crowded; more chances to get a seat, more leg & elbow room, no rowdy kids, food orders brought to your seat in Germany...

The extra costs you may consider with the pass are the reservations:

- Within Germany and Netherlands, you can hop on any train you want. Reservations are possible but optional within Germany.
- The ICE between Frankfurt and Amsterdam may have been made reservation-mandatory this summer for the holiday peak; an exception. Reservations can be done at DB (train stations & the DB Navigator app) for a nominal price. The Intercity between Hannover and Amsterdam is an an alternative; you can board without reservations although it can be crowded.
- Eurostar can be a challenge. Passholder tickets cost a nominal fee, can already be sold out even if there are seats left on the train.
- Sleeper trains are a great time-saver. You can swallow nearly 1000km while sleeping. They are so successful that some route can be sold out weeks in advance. Reservation fees depend on the accommodation you choose.  On Nightjets:

  - Couchette 39€-59€, padded bunk in room of 6- or 4-person
    mixed-sex or women-only compartments
  - Sleeping car can be 80€ and above but a decent experience
    with actual beds, max. 3 in the same room, breakfast included, shower in the car or next to your room, there can be special discounts. And if lucky you can end up having the room to yourself
  - Personal advice: get a couchette at least. If you dare taking the seated carriage to save money, your mileage may vary. Can be compartments in which the lights can be turned off, or a regular seated car with bright lights all night long and no way to secure you belongings.

The ferry can be partially covered, depending on the line. Some lines offer discounts to passholders on the passage (not cabins), listed on the Interrail website.

Another creative approach to get through Germany is possible: D-Ticket. For 49€ per calendar month, you get unlimited travel on all the country using the "slow" trains (regional lines, no IC / ICE) and most local transportation (bus, tram, subway / u-bahn...). You can subscribe from the DB Navigator app. The twist: you cannot pay by card; only by bank transfer using an IBAN, and have to think about revoking it after you are done not to be automatically charged the next month. A Revolut account works, personally tested.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a nightjet couchette at 39 euros, or even 59

Comment: This is the reservation supplement for an Interrail pass; clearly not the normal fare!

Comment: oh, I see. That explains why it looks so cheap! (I'm not super familiar with the interrail system, but it looks quite complicated!)

Answer (score 2):

One can simply use Google Maps to get an itinerary that doesn’t use the plane:

[image]

I don’t understand the other requirements, as they seem to contradict with one another. Minimizing time is typically at odds with minimizing the cost. And using a ship typically won’t help minimize the time spent.

Comment: A ship, like a night train, may offer you the (theoretical) advantage of travelling while sleeping, so you can maximize your "awake" time ... my experience is that slepeing while travelling can be a hit-and-miss thing.

Comment: ...and I guess ships are mostly rather expensive